# Get RSS feed about plugin new update

Tags: rss, updates

I would like to know if there is a way to get a rss feed when one of the plugin of my website is available.

Indeed, I need to manage updates of some website, but I don't want to lose my time connecting on those websites to see if there are really some plugin updates... So getting a rss feed would be perfect.

Is it possible to do it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your main goal is to get notified in new plugin updates, then you can easily accomplish this with a plugin. Update Notifier.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/update-notifier/

Answer (score 0):

Every plugin on the official repository has a Development Log RSS Feed, under the Developers tab.

It's got much more than just plugin updates on new versions (it tracks every activity on the SVN), but it works.

Comment: yeah but actually the only stuff i m interested in is getting updates alerts. So i think the "update notifier" plugin suggested by Ronny is better for me. Thank you.